# parsing xml into sql columns

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery, sql-server-openxml

I need to parse values from XML to SQL column's

XML looks like this

```xml
<GetCategorySpecificsResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2020-11-22T23:17:48.772Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Success</Ack>
    <Version>1179</Version>
    <Build>E1179_CORE_API6_19296588_R1</Build>
    <Recommendations>
        <CategoryID>22422</CategoryID>
        <NameRecommendation>
            <Name>Binding</Name>
            <ValidationRules>
                <ValueType>Text</ValueType>
                <MaxValues>1</MaxValues>
                <SelectionMode>FreeText</SelectionMode>
                <UsageConstraint>Optional</UsageConstraint>
            </ValidationRules>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Cloth</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Disbound</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Fine Binding</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Hardcover</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Leather</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Loose Pages</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Unbound</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Vellum</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
        </NameRecommendation>
        <NameRecommendation>
            <Name>Subject</Name>
            <ValidationRules>
                <ValueType>Text</ValueType>
                <MaxValues>1</MaxValues>
                <SelectionMode>FreeText</SelectionMode>
                <UsageConstraint>Optional</UsageConstraint>
            </ValidationRules>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Art</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Children's</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>History</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Law</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Literature</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Medicine</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Natural Science</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Philosophy</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Reference</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Religion, Bibles</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Science &amp; Technology</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Travel</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
        </NameRecommendation>
        <NameRecommendation>
            <Name>Original/Facsimile</Name>
            <ValidationRules>
                <ValueType>Text</ValueType>
                <MaxValues>1</MaxValues>
                <SelectionMode>FreeText</SelectionMode>
                <UsageConstraint>Optional</UsageConstraint>
            </ValidationRules>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Original</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Facsimile</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Unknown</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
        </NameRecommendation>
        <NameRecommendation>
            <Name>Date of Publication</Name>
            <ValidationRules>
                <ValueType>Text</ValueType>
                <MaxValues>1</MaxValues>
                <SelectionMode>FreeText</SelectionMode>
                <UsageConstraint>Optional</UsageConstraint>
            </ValidationRules>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Unknown</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <HelpText>Please indicate the year when the book was published (between 1454-1540)</HelpText>
        </NameRecommendation>
        <NameRecommendation>
            <Name>Language</Name>
            <ValidationRules>
                <ValueType>Text</ValueType>
                <MaxValues>1</MaxValues>
                <SelectionMode>FreeText</SelectionMode>
                <UsageConstraint>Optional</UsageConstraint>
            </ValidationRules>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Arabic</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Bengali</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Bulgarian</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Chinese</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Czech</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Danish</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Dutch</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>English</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Finnish</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>French</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>German</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Greek</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Hebrew</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Hindi/Urdu</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Hungarian</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Irish</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Italian</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Japanese</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Korean</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Latin</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Latvian</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Lithuanian</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Malay</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Norwegian</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Polish</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Portuguese</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Russian</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Serbian</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Slovenian</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Spanish</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Swedish</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Turkish</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Vietnamese</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Welsh</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
        </NameRecommendation>
        <NameRecommendation>
            <Name>Special Attributes</Name>
            <ValidationRules>
                <ValueType>Text</ValueType>
                <MaxValues>30</MaxValues>
                <SelectionMode>FreeText</SelectionMode>
                <UsageConstraint>Optional</UsageConstraint>
            </ValidationRules>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>First Edition</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Illustrated</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Signed</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>With Dust Jacket</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
        </NameRecommendation>
        <NameRecommendation>
            <Name>Region</Name>
            <ValidationRules>
                <ValueType>Text</ValueType>
                <MaxValues>1</MaxValues>
                <SelectionMode>FreeText</SelectionMode>
                <UsageConstraint>Optional</UsageConstraint>
            </ValidationRules>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Africa</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Antarctica</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Asia</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Australia, Oceania</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Europe</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Middle East</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>North America</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>South America</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
        </NameRecommendation>
        <NameRecommendation>
            <Name>Publisher</Name>
            <ValidationRules>
                <ValueType>Text</ValueType>
                <MaxValues>1</MaxValues>
                <SelectionMode>FreeText</SelectionMode>
                <UsageConstraint>Optional</UsageConstraint>
            </ValidationRules>
        </NameRecommendation>
        <NameRecommendation>
            <Name>Place of Publication</Name>
            <ValidationRules>
                <ValueType>Text</ValueType>
                <MaxValues>1</MaxValues>
                <SelectionMode>FreeText</SelectionMode>
                <UsageConstraint>Optional</UsageConstraint>
            </ValidationRules>
        </NameRecommendation>
        <NameRecommendation>
            <Name>Author</Name>
            <ValidationRules>
                <ValueType>Text</ValueType>
                <MaxValues>1</MaxValues>
                <SelectionMode>FreeText</SelectionMode>
                <UsageConstraint>Optional</UsageConstraint>
            </ValidationRules>
        </NameRecommendation>
        <NameRecommendation>
            <Name>California Prop 65 Warning</Name>
            <ValidationRules>
                <ValueType>Text</ValueType>
                <MaxValues>1</MaxValues>
                <SelectionMode>FreeText</SelectionMode>
                <AspectUsage>Instance</AspectUsage>
                <MaxValueLength>800</MaxValueLength>
                <UsageConstraint>Optional</UsageConstraint>
                <VariationSpecifics>Disabled</VariationSpecifics>
            </ValidationRules>
            <HelpText>California Proposition 65 requires businesses to provide warnings to Californians about significant exposure to chemicals that cause cancer, birth defects, or other reproductive harm. Add details about the warning you want to show California buyers. We'll add a warning symbol and the word 'WARNING:' before the description you enter here, and we’ll add 'For more information go to www.P65Warnings.ca.gov' following your description.</HelpText>
        </NameRecommendation>
    </Recommendations>
    <Recommendations>
        <CategoryID>23048</CategoryID>
        <NameRecommendation>
            <Name>Material</Name>
            <ValidationRules>
                <ValueType>Text</ValueType>
                <MaxValues>1</MaxValues>
                <SelectionMode>FreeText</SelectionMode>
                <UsageConstraint>Recommended</UsageConstraint>
            </ValidationRules>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Paper</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Papyrus</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Parchment</Value>
                <ValidationRules />
            </ValueRecommendation>
            <ValueRecommendation>
                <Value>Vellum</Value>
            </ValueRecommendation>
        </NameRecommendation>
    </Recommendations>
</GetCategorySpecificsResponse>
```

What I've tried is:

```
USE OPENXMLTesting
GO

DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML_2
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML


SELECT Category_ID, NameRecomendation
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'GetCategorySpecificsResponse/Recomendations')
WITH 
(
Category_ID [varchar](100) 'Category_ID',
NameRecomendation [varchar](100) 'NameRecommendation'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

But i always get empty table. Since i can't parse the first level it's nonsense to go further to get
Final solution would contain columns.

1. CategoryID, NameRecommendation/Name ,
2. NameRecommendation/ValidationRules/SelectionMode
3. NameRecommendation/ValidationRules/UsageConstraint
4. NameRecommendation/ValidationRules/ValueType
5. NameRecommendation/ValueRecommendation/Value

Comment: `sp_xml_preparedocument` is a **really** old way of parsing XML is SQL Server; XQuery has been available since at least SQL Server 2008 (maybe even 2005).

Comment: What are your expected results here as well?

Comment: @Larnu first would be to get all available CategoryID from XML .. And final approach is to get those 5 columns listed in question

Comment: Before anything, you'll need to fix the XML; it's not valid. That is why what you have isn't working either. To parse XML it needs to be valid. In the above, for example, `GetCategorySpecificsResponse` is never closed.

Comment: @Larnu sorry. I just copied few nodes. File is over 1.2 GB's. I fixed the missing tag

Comment: We don't need the whole thing, just a small and reasonable representation of it (that's valid).

Comment: @Larnu i think it's valid XML now. i closed tags and validated xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without expected results, this is a guess, but returns results and should be enough for you to fill in the gaps:

```sql
DECLARE @XML = {Your XML};

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents')
SELECT GCSR.R.value('(CategoryID/text())[1]','int') AS CategoryID,
       R.NR.value('(Name/text())[1]','varchar(20)') AS [Name],
       R.NR.value('(ValidationRules/UsageConstraint/text())[1]','varchar(20)') AS UsageConstraint,
       NR.VR.value('(Value/text())[1]','varchar(20)') AS [Value]
FROM (VALUES(@XML))V(X)
     CROSS APPLY V.X.nodes('GetCategorySpecificsResponse/Recommendations')GCSR(R)
     CROSS APPLY GCSR.R.nodes('./NameRecommendation')R(NR)
     CROSS APPLY R.NR.nodes('./ValueRecommendation') NR(VR);
```

Comment: That's more than i needed. Thanks for your time

Comment: just to have in mind. Output is over 10 milion of rows in 3 minute. Good job